# What happens to files that are checked out, when working-tree-encoding chanages in .gitattributes

Tags: git, checkout, gitattributes

I assume if I had a `.gitattributes` file thus

```
*.abc working-tree-encoding=ISO8859-1 text
```

And committed a file `123.abc` and then changed the `.gitattributes` file to

```
*.abc working-tree-encoding=IBM-1047 text
```

A "git checkout" of the file will mean its encoding would be changed to IBM-1047.

But what if the original `.gitattributes` file was

```
*.abc binary
```

and the `123.abc` file is committed and the `.gitattributes` file change to

```
*.abc working-tree-encoding=IBM-1047 text
```

Would a `git checkout` of the file cause the file to come back as binary (because it was committed as binary) or would Git assume the file was stored internally as `UTF-` and attempt to create a `IBM-1047` encoded file.

Comment: This is not at all clear from the documentation. Also, due to the way Git tries hard not to bother touching files it doesn't think have "changed"—which ignores changes to `.gitattributes`—you might find odd results from experimentation, too.

Comment: In short, I don't know what *would* happen, or what *should* happen. :-)

Comment: Thanks I'll have a play and report back